# my checkbox doesn't seem instanceof CheckBox

Tags: java, android, checkbox, instanceof

Working on my thesis I'm gettin a warning in LogCat that I think might affect my code.

I receive a JSON with some data and I have to bild a layout with checkbox and radiobutton (in RadioGroup) programmatically. Later I can vote this survey and here is my problem cause when I getChildAt() in my layout

```
if(child instanceof CheckBox)
```

doesn't work and I can't understand why.

Here is my code:

```
 ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSurvey);  //OnCreate

    /*Creating CheckBox*/
            String votes = jObj.getString("votes");
            String label = jObj.getString("label");
            String usid = jObj.getString("USID");    
            if(uType.equals("multi")){
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(SingleSurvey.this);
                cb.setText(label + " (" + votes + ")");
                cb.setId(s+1000);
                ll.addView(cb);         
                Log.i("MULTI_TYPE", "usid: " + usid + " id: " + cb.getId());
            }
            s++;

    /*Voting*/

            for(int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++){
                View child = ll.getChildAt(i);
                int p = child.getId();
                Log.i("CHILD ID", "id: " + p);

                if(child instanceof TextView){
                    continue;
                }

                else if(child instanceof CheckBox){
                    Log.i("INSTANCE OF CB", "checkbox");
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) child;
                    if(cb.isChecked()){
                        int cbId = cb.getId();
                        usid = rb_usid[cbId];
                        Log.i("CHECKBOX", "usid: " + usid);
                    }
                }

                //some other stuff
            }
```

Comment: Ok. I'm going to slap me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Checkbox` class is a `TextView` subclass, so your code will never enter the `else if` block, which is what the warning is saying.

```
    android.widget.TextView
       ↳android.widget.Button
           ↳android.widget.CompoundButton
               ↳android.widget.CheckBox
```